# Appending data in a list

Tags: java

I have a league table that shows the league ranking of the teams in the league. 
This data originates in Firebase and I have a custom defined object that defines the list.

The challenge I'm having is that I need to also need to add an additional value into the returned list array (leagueList).
The firebase database does not hold the rank (1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, etc....) as the league is determined ordering the teams by points. 
I need to add in 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, etc... in addition.

Do I do this in the class that defines the list? Or do I have to write some extra handling code that admends `leagueList` below;

```
for (DataSnapshot matchSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
    league_List match = matchSnapshot.getValue(league_List.class);
    leagueList.add(match);
}
```

The class that describes the list definition is:

```
public class league_List {

    String teamName;
    Integer played;
    Integer goalsScored;
    Integer goalsConceded;
    Integer points;

    public league_List(Integer rankNo) {

    }

    public league_List(String teamName, Integer played, Integer goalsScored, Integer goalsConceded, Integer points) {
        this.teamName = teamName;
        this.played = played;
        this.goalsScored = goalsScored;
        this.goalsConceded = goalsConceded;
        this.points = points;
    }

    public String getTeamName() {
        return teamName;
    }

    public Integer getPlayed() {
        return played;
    }

    public Integer getGoalsScored() {
        return goalsScored;
    }

    public Integer getGoalsConceded() {
        return goalsConceded;
    }

    public Integer getPoints() {
        return points;
    }

}
```

Comment: You'd better name you Classes with explicit names ^^ `league_list` is not one (and apparently nothing to do with 'list')

Comment: You will increase the clarity of the code if your names would be unique and you will use the java convention (in this case class name should be in CamelCase)

Comment: what data structure you are using for your `leagueList`? and you can add a filed in your BO named `rank' for your case (it is not necessary that all fields in your BO needs to map with the database).

Answer (score 0):

You should rename your `league_List` class to `Team` (because that is what it seems to be), and your `leagueList` should be a List of `Teams`

Your `Team` class should have a rank attribute, this way:

```
class Team {

    String teamName;
    Integer played;
    Integer goalsScored;
    Integer goalsConceded;
    Integer points;
    int rank;

    public Team() {}

    public Team(String teamName, Integer played, Integer goalsScored, Integer goalsConceded, Integer points) {
        this.teamName = teamName;
        this.played = played;
        this.goalsScored = goalsScored;
        this.goalsConceded = goalsConceded;
        this.points = points;
    }

    // Getters/Setters    

}
```

Then you can do your program this way:

```
private List<Team> leagueList = new ArrayList<>();

// Get all your teams
for (DataSnapshot matchSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
    Team team = matchSnapshot.getValue(Team.class);
    leagueList.add(team);
}

// Sort the teams by points
leagueList.sort(Comparator.comparing(Team::getPoints));

// Give each team its rank
for(int i=leagueList.size(); i>0; i--) {
    leagueList.get(i-1).setRank(i);
}
```

A better way would have a `League` object with a `Team` list inside it and a ranking. This way the team itself does not know its rank. This would be the concern of the `League` class